# Building Gem - InvalidSpecificationException […] are not files

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems

This issue has been brought up several times. Past solutions have revolved around Git files not added and committed. What should one do if, by all accounts, Git has been properly handled and the error still appears.

```
rake aborted!
Gem::InvalidSpecificationException: ["Gemfile", "Gemfile.lock", 
"lib/sysstandards/ext/abstract_interface.rb", 
"lib/sysstandards/ext/mainframe_constants.rb", 
"lib/sysstandards/ext/text_box_formatters.rb", "spec/ext", 
"spec/ext/abstract_interface_spec.rb", 
"spec/ext/text_box_formatters_spec.rb"] are not files
```

All the files listed above were new files. They were added to the repository. They were committed. The branch was positioned to master. The child branch was merged into master.

```
dvn@mint01 ~/RubymineProjects/SysStandards $ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

The files show in the git listing.

```
dvn@mint01 ~/RubymineProjects/SysStandards $ git ls-files
Gemfile 
Gemfile.lock
...
lib/sysstandards.rb
lib/sysstandards/chgtable.rb
lib/sysstandards/ext/abstract_interface.rb
lib/sysstandards/ext/file_flocked.rb
lib/sysstandards/ext/load_params.rb
lib/sysstandards/ext/mainframe_constants.rb
lib/sysstandards/ext/text_box_formatters.rb
...
spec/ext/abstract_interface_spec.rb
spec/ext/text_box_formatters_spec.rb
```

I'm really lost on this one. I have looked at the similar questions, followed their advice, but to no avail. I cannot get around this, thus, I cannot get the gem built. Please let me know what other information you may require.

I'm on the verge of deleting .git and starting from scratch. But there is a lot of history that will be lost if I do. I'll wait until Monday to see if anyone has any guidance. But on Monday, I think I'll ditch Git and switch to Fossil.

Thanks for your time and consideration,
dvn

**Update to issue showing gemspec**

```
spec = Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name = 'SysStandards'
  s.version = '3.0.0'
  s.has_rdoc = true
  s.extra_rdoc_files = ['readme.md', 'LICENSE']
  s.summary = 'Standards Library'
  s.description = s.summary
  s.author = 'Don V Nielsen'
  s.email = 'donvnielsen@gmail.com'
  # s.executables = ['your_executable_here']
  s.files = %w(LICENSE readme.md Rakefile Gemfile Gemfile.lock Rakefile) + Dir.glob("{lib,spec}/**/*")
  s.require_path = "lib"
  s.bindir = "bin"
end

GEM
rake (12.0.0)
rspec (3.5.0)

PLATFORMS
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux]
x64-mingw32
x86-mingw32

BUNDLED WITH
1.10.6
```

**Update with file listings**

```
dvn@mint01 ~/RubymineProjects/SysStandards $ ls -l
total 40
drwx------ 2 dvn dvn 4096 Oct 30 11:16 coverage
drwxr-xr-x 2 dvn dvn 4096 Feb 23 09:46 doc
-rw-r--r-- 1 dvn dvn  139 Feb 23 12:20 Gemfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 dvn dvn  629 Feb 23 12:20 Gemfile.lock
drwxr-xr-x 3 dvn dvn 4096 Feb 23 12:20 lib
-rw-r--r-- 2 dvn dvn   65 Apr  1  2013 LICENSE
drwxr-xr-x 3 dvn dvn 4096 Feb 22 18:38 pkg
-rw-r--r-- 1 dvn dvn 1169 Feb 23 15:39 Rakefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 dvn dvn  890 Feb 23 12:20 readme.md
drwx------ 6 dvn dvn 4096 Feb 23 12:20 spec
dvn@mint01 ~/RubymineProjects/SysStandards $ ls -l ./lib/sysstandards/ext
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 dvn dvn 1259 Feb 23 12:20 abstract_interface.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 dvn dvn  388 Feb 23 12:20 file_flocked.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 dvn dvn  345 Feb 23 12:20 load_params.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 dvn dvn  540 Feb 23 12:20 mainframe_constants.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 dvn dvn 1366 Feb 23 12:20 text_box_formatters.rb
dvn@mint01 ~/RubymineProjects/SysStandards $ ls -l ./spec/ext
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 dvn dvn 747 Feb 23 12:20 abstract_interface_spec.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 dvn dvn 941 Feb 23 12:20 text_box_formatters_spec.rb
```

**So What is File.symlink**

The exception is thrown from the following code in gem::specification.rb:

```
@files.delete_if            { |x| File.directory?(x) && !File.symlink?(x) }
@test_files.delete_if       { |x| File.directory?(x) && !File.symlink?(x) }
@executables.delete_if      { |x| File.directory?(File.join(@bindir, x)) }
@extra_rdoc_files.delete_if { |x| File.directory?(x) && !File.symlink?(x) }
@extensions.delete_if       { |x| File.directory?(x) && !File.symlink?(x) }

non_files = files.reject { |x| File.file?(x) || File.symlink?(x) }

unless not packaging or non_files.empty? then
  raise Gem::InvalidSpecificationException,
        "[\"#{non_files.join "\", \""}\"] are not files"
end
```

@files comes into this code holding 46 entries: files and directories. The @files.delete_if should remove the directories, and the result is 36 remaining entries. Among the 36 survivors is 'spec/ext', which is a directory per 'ls -l':

```
dvn@mint01 ~/RubymineProjects/SysStandards/spec $ ls -l
total 32
-rw-r--r-- 1 dvn dvn 1353 Feb 23 12:20 change_table_spec.rb
drwx------ 3 dvn dvn 4096 Oct 30 11:17 data
drwxr-xr-x 2 dvn dvn 4096 Feb 23 12:20 ext
```

When files.reject is executed, the result is seven entries in non_files: the one directory and six files. This is the cause of the exception. So it appears that File.symlink? is triggering the issue. What is a File.symlink, what sets the value, and how does the value get set?

Comment: Just a hunch: I don't think this is a git issue, rather a gem building issue. Could you post the snippet of gemspec code with the s.files = ... and the versions of ruby, rake, bundler, and gem in use?

Comment: What does `ls -l` show? (Also `ls -l` for the various sub dirs listed in the error message). The error [appears to be caused when you are trying to add something that isn’t a normal file](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/v2.6.8/lib/rubygems/specification.rb#L2687-L2692).

Comment: File listing as follows:

Comment: Updated with file listings. I don't see anything unusual. Could it be line endings? Everything should be standard linux line endings.

Comment: Everything there looks normal. I don’t think line endings would affect this. What does the Rake task do—is it doing something like copying files to a build directory and building the gem from there perhaps?

Comment: I just do "rake gem" on the command line, and it is fed the specification. No behaviors are coded into the Rakefile.

Comment: There must be a `gem` task defined somewhere—does the `Rakefile` require any files?

Comment: I wonder if removing the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock from the files array fixes it? It's my understanding that they're not supposed to be in the gemspec files list - see [here](https://github.com/radar/guides/issues/14)

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the /pkg folder and re-running `rake gem` fixed the problem.

The problem stemmed from the existing /pkg folder. I identified the problem by adding `puts Dir.getwd` to Rakefile and specification.rb. Rakefile gathered the project files from my project folder and specification.rb gathered files from the package build folder.

```
Rakefile     : /home/dvn/RubymineProjects/SysStandards
Specification: /home/dvn/RubymineProjects/SysStandards/pkg/SysStandards-3.0.0
```

So, for reasons unknown, the package build folder was not being updated with the added/changed files. I'm assuming some decision determined that the folder did not require updating.

Deleting the /pkg folder fixed the problem, forcing the gem process to rebuild its pkg build folder, thus copying the affected files.

I'm concerned that Gemfile and Rakefile were ending up in the `non_files` list. Those two files have been present in the project from the very beginning; they are not new files. So what exactly triggered them to go in.

Unfortunately, I was an idiot. I solved the problem by deleting the /pkg folder. I should have renamed it, keeping its contents. Duh. Now I have nothing to compare against.

Comment: I just duplicated the problem by adding Gemfile.lock to s.files in the Rakefile. That explains why Gemfile and Rakefile were ending up in non_files list. I had added those files to s.files, but they would not have been present in the build folder.  I really hope someone benefits from this, because it was a lot of writing to simply result in "just delete the /pkg folder and rerun."